# Dealing with square brackets in regular expressions in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm converting a CSV file from the database of the Geeklog CMS to WordPress posts. Unfortunately, it contains soms 'autotags' (similar to the 'shortcodes' in WordPress), with square brackets.

I want to replace several hundreds of them to normal HTML code with search+replace in Notepad++ but can't find a way to deal with the square brackets.

This is the 'autotag' from Geeklog:
[story:theslugofthepost13122005 The Anchor Text Of The Post]

I've found out that I can convert the `"[story"` part to `<a href="` with the RegEx `"\[]story"` but can't find a way to find/select/convert the rest of the autotag. Any help woud be very appreciated!

Comment: can you show example input & expected output?

Comment: The "replace with" field was '<a href="http://www.\1' which resulted in '<a href="http://www.theslugofthepost13122005 The Anchor Text Of The Post]' but that's only one part of the conversion. I tried to select more with '[[\[]story:][0-9A-z]\s[0-9A-z][\[]]' but that gave several errors and no output.

Comment: ok, cool, think I understood your initial question then, check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the replace options to `Regular Expression`:

I used this: (from what I could make out from your post):

```
Find What:    \[story:(\w+)\s+((\w+\s*)+)?\]
Replace With: <a href="$1">$2</a>
```

It replaces

```
[story:theslugofthepost13122005 The Anchor Text Of The Post]
```

with

```
<a href="theslugofthepost13122005">The Anchor Text Of The Post</a>
```

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, your main problem was that you were not escaping the square brackets, as they denote a character class in regex, so for example: `[` should be `\[`

Comment: Many thanks, it works pefectly! I tried to escape the square brackets but got confused since I thought I should to use them as well to select parts of that autotag. And after a few hours trying to figure it out, my headache grew and grew... Many, many thanks!!